# Let text go through a div

Tags: css

Ok, this is for a survey where the div is the chart just like you see it on facebook.

Basically:

```
<div style='border:1px solid black;width:300px;'>    
<div style='width:100px;???'>This text is longer than the inner div tag.</div>
</div>
```

...but I want the text not to break and go directly through the div. Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `white-space: nowrap`. Ensure your `div` and its relevant ancestors don't have `overflow: hidden` otherwise you won't see the text as it leaves the element.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5gQh/).

Comment: Thank you for the heads up about "overflow: hidden." That was my issue.

Answer (score 0):

### CSS

```
word-wrap:nowrap;
```

Causes the text not to wrap. See [word-wrap on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/word-wrap) for more information.